# iOS UICollectionView change color of the selected item

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to change the color of the selected item in my UICollectionView, also item that are not selected should have a default color. But sometimes there are more than two items are selected and sometimes none.

My code is:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell * cell;
    StanderdScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell * standardScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"StanderdScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(standardScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell.selected || selectedPlayerIndex == indexPath.row){
        standardScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell.outerView.backgroundColor = NAV_BAR_BARTINT_COLOR_GREEN;
    }
    else{
        standardScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell.outerView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xC9C9C9);
    }

    cell = standardScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell;
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView       didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    StanderdScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.outerView.backgroundColor = NAV_BAR_BARTINT_COLOR_GREEN;
    selectedPlayerIndex = indexPath.row;
    [self displayDataWithPlayer:selectedPlayerIndex andHole:selectedHoleIndex];
}

- (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    StanderdScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.outerView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xC9C9C9);
}
```

`selectedPlayerIndex` always points to the selected player and it is declared 1 in viewDidLoad. How do i solve this?

Comment: ADD out put Screen Short if you can

Comment: I think you want to manage this like we manage check unCheck items...Right??

Comment: You need to manage state of background color in array or dictionary and use it in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @GouravJoshi not like checkbox but like a radio button

Comment: @SailendraKumar I've registered a cell in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, change your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` like this

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell * cell;

    StanderdScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell * standardScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"StanderdScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if(selectedPlayerIndex == indexPath.row)
    {
        standardScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell.outerView.backgroundColor = NAV_BAR_BARTINT_COLOR_GREEN;
    }
    else
    {
        standardScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell.outerView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xC9C9C9);
    }

    cell = standardScoreCardPlayerCollectionViewCell;
}
return cell;
}
```

and `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` like this

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView       didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedPlayerIndex = indexPath.row;

    [self displayDataWithPlayer:selectedPlayerIndex andHole:selectedHoleIndex];

    [collectionView reloadData];
}
```

also no need to implement `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` remove that method

Comment: Yeah its working now :) But is it good to reload collection view for every selection?

Comment: Well it will depend your requirement, as right now you are just setting the background color of cell, also in this case you can just reload two cells, first cell of previously selected indexpath and one cell for currently selected indexpath